# TLS 1.2 Server sending also CA Chain

Tags: c#, ssl, server, tls1.2, .net-4.7.2

I'm the server and for some weird reason other than the server certificate I also have to send right after that the ca-chain.
How do I do it in .net framework 4.7.2 ?

```
public void StartListen(string ip, int port)
{
    _Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);    
    Ip = ip;    
    _Listener.Start();    
    _Certificate = new X509Certificate2(CERTIFICATE_PATH);
    _Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientConnection, null);
}

private void OnClientConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var client = _Listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(),true,(sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true, 
        ((sender, host, certificates, certificate, issuers) => null));
    try {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(_Certificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
        ...
    ...
...
```

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGBLz.png)

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPV0N.png)

Comment: Why are you passing the fourth parameter `userCertificateSelectionCallback` to the `SslStream` constructor? The default callback will automatically pass the CA chain. Side note: why not use the more modern `await` syntax?

Comment: _I'm the server_: Are you an AI?

Comment: The normal way is to send the entire chain of certificates *except* the root certificate, in order of server certificate first. That's not weird.